# Installation of Ubuntu 20.04.01 triple booth in MacbookPro Retina alongside Windows does not work

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 20.04 triple boot in MacBook pro mid-2015 and windows does not work I've been trying for a long time all different partition methods including dual EFI and installing windows first on the mac but every time I install Ubuntu 20, it halts

I tried to refind, didn't work, installing windows through Bootcamp doesn't work
repartitioning drive either with MacOS Catalina, Ubuntu Gparted or diskpart and finally with windows either diskpart or generating partitions with the regular disk partition software, tried exFAT, fat for UEFI, tried ext4 and fat32 for swap and on and on.

I used to have the triple boot with fedora until I decided to get a 2TB nvme SSD (formatted to GPT) IT HAS BEEN HELL! since the question has not been completely answered that means it is not duplicate. but if someone out there can see this and has broken through, I would most definitely appreciate and update because the boot drive has no issues and I would love to use this flavor but I have researched everywhere and no complete answer even videos on YouTube and different blogs never complete the reason or are outdated.

Appreciate your help &)

Comment: I also reset the ram and SNC on the mac with no luck

Comment: also disabled system integrity protection while using refind

Comment: Here it is hidden somwhere!!!"UEFI with CSM" usually means mixed mode in which both native (UEFI) and CSM-based (BIOS) boot is available. The boot menu will show a mix of native UEFI boot entries and CSM "bootable disk" entries in this case.

However, one important side effect of disabling CSM is that it'll allow certain UEFI-only features to be activated (such as "fast boot"), at the same time preventing some BIOS-only features (such as PCI option ROM support).

It is possible that "fast boot" (despite being made for Windows 10) is somewhat buggy and breaks the boot process.